# Login cause loop with error

Tags: 14.04, unity, virtualbox, login, login-screen

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Oracle VM on a laptop : GS60 6QE.

Use to have graphic problem with Ubuntu, but at least I can work.
Suddenly I can't login normally.

I'm on it for hours now ... If someone can help me  :

After I login, I've time to see some errors. I can click and cancel them, but after 1/2 sec, restart.

[image]

After each try, the `/var/log` file gain ~ 700 MB, and my session is soon full

Here is a `cat .xsession-errors` (just the end, I don't know how to scroll from shell)

[image]
[image]

`.Xauthority` and `/tmp` are good, I also tried to reinstall unity.

I appreciate any help. Thanks !

Comment: After ctrl + Alt + F1 I tried cat .xession-errors.   I am getting no such file or directory